# collection.findOne always gets executed last

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, for-loop, mongoose

I dont understand why the command at the bottom gets executed before the code in the mongoose/function.

```
router.post("/path", function(req, res, next) {
    for(var i = 0; i < req.body.getname.length; i++) {
       Bun.findOne({title: req.body.getname[i]}, function(err, data) {
          console.log("second")
       })
    }
    console.log("first")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The findOne method is an asynchronous method that waits for a response before executing its callback. In your case immediately the `for loop` starts the asynchronous call is executed first, however because the response isn't received yet, the code continues with the line with code `console.log("first")`. After it receives a receives a response from the findOne it executes whatever code is in the callback.

To get the line to execute before the code in the callback try any of these 2

```
router.post("/path", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("first")
    for(var i = 0; i < req.body.getname.length; i++) {
        Bun.findOne({title: req.body.getname[i]}, function(err, data) {
            console.log("second");
        });
    }
});
```

OR

```
router.post("/path", function(req, res, next) {
    for(var i = 0; i < req.body.getname.length; i++) {
        Bun.findOne({title: req.body.getname[i]}, function(err, data) {
            //Bring that line first
            console.log("first");

            console.log("second");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay do you have an idea on how to fix it? Or an alternative?

Comment: It is not an error. What you should rather do is put the `console.log("first")` code before the `console.log("second")` but all in the callback. So all will execute after the request gets a response.